# Pandas Create dataframe from Key Value pair dictionary

Tags: pandas

Assume I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
{
   "model1": 0.5,
   "model2": 0.6,
   "model3": 0.7
}
```

How would I load it into a pandas dataframe such that it has the following structure:

| Name | Accuracy |
| --- | --- |
| model1 | 0.5 |
| model2 | 0.6 |
| model3 | 0.7 |

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc of `from_dict` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: I did, but it does not help due to the structure of the dictionary. To load it as I wish, I had to re-shape the dict itself. I was wondering if the same could have been achieved with this dict structure.